# Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start with ChromeDriver and Selenium

Tags: php, selenium, raspberry-pi, facebook-php-webdriver, php-webdriver

What are you trying to achieve? (Expected behavior)

I am trying to get the example.php to run successfully with no errors.

What do you get instead? (Actual behavior)

I get an error 500 and the following error in the log:

```
[Wed Oct 10 19:46:41.597926 2018] [:error] [pid 3951] [client 162.158.38.241:62198] 
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\\WebDriver\\Exception\\UnknownServerException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.\n
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'\n
System info: host: 'raspberrypi', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'arm', os.version: '4.14.70-v7+', java.version: '1.8.0_181'\n
Driver info: driver.version: unknown in /var/www/html/selenium/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:114\nStack trace:\n
    #0 /var/www/html/selenium/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php(326): Facebook\\WebDriver\\Exception\\WebDriverException::throwException(13, 'Timed out waiti...', Array)\n
    #1 /var/www/html/selenium/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php(126): Facebook\\WebDriver\\Remote\\HttpCommandExecutor->execute(Object(Facebook\\WebDriver\\Remote\\WebDriverCommand))\n
    #2 /var/www/html/selenium/index.php(21): Facebook\\WebDriver\\Remote\\RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhos...', Object(Facebook\\WebDriver\\Remote\\DesiredCapabiliti in /var/www/html/selenium/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php on line 114
```

How could the issue be reproduced? (Steps to reproduce)

I am using Raspbian Stretch on a Raspberry Pi Model 2 B+. I have the selenium jar file installed in the same directory as the PHP webdriver client (installed via Composer) and the jar file seems to run fine on port 4444.

```
<?php // An example of using php-webdriver. 
// Do not forget to run composer install before and also have Selenium server started and listening on port 4444. 
namespace Facebook\WebDriver; 
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities; 
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver; 
require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); 

// start Chrome with 5 second timeout 
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; 

// this is the default 
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome(); 
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000); 

// navigate to 'http://www.seleniumhq.org/' 
$driver->get('https://www.seleniumhq.org/'); 

// adding cookie 
$driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies(); 
$cookie = new Cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value'); 
$driver->manage()->addCookie($cookie); 
$cookies = $driver->manage()->getCookies(); 
print_r($cookies); 

// click the link 'About' 
$link = $driver->findElement( WebDriverBy::id('menu_about') ); 
$link->click(); 

// wait until the page is loaded 
$driver->wait()->until( WebDriverExpectedCondition::titleContains('About') ); 

// print the title of the current page 
echo "The title is '" . $driver->getTitle() . "'\n"; 

// print the URI of the current page 
echo "The current URI is '" . $driver->getCurrentURL() . "'\n"; 

// write 'php' in the search box 
$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('q')) ->sendKeys('php') 

// fill the search 

box ->submit(); 

// submit the whole form 
// wait at most 10 seconds until at least one result is shown 

$driver->wait(10)->until( 
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(WebDriverBy::className('gsc-result')) 
); 

// close the browser 
$driver->quit();
```

I believe that chromedriver is the source of the problem, although I don't understand how as I installed it correctly using the command

```
wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/chromedriver_linux64.zip 
&& sudo unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/;
```

and then again in the same selenium directory, to no avail.

Information:

- Php-webdriver version: 1.6.0
- PHP version: 7.0.30-0+deb9u1
- Selenium server version: 3.14.0
- Operating system: Raspbian Stretch
- Browser used + version: Chromium Browser, version 65.0.3325.181-0+rpt4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** instance was unable to start the *driver server*.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.42* from `https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/chromedriver_linux64.zip`
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.42*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v68-70**

- You are using *Chromium Browser v65.0* which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.42* and the *Chrome Browser v65.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.42**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v68-70*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.42 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.